# How to override material-ui css with styled component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm still a beginner with the ui-material. And I would like to custom my own Button Component with `styled-component`.

The problem is to override the css according to the button variations, for example if it is `primary` or `secondary`:

Here's my code into [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-cdn-whznl?file=/src/index.js)

```js
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { CButton } from "./styles";

const CustomButton = ({ children, color }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CButton variant="contained" color={color}>
        {children}
      </CButton>
    </div>
  );
};

CustomButton.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  color: PropTypes.oneOf(["primary", "secondary"])
};

export default CustomButton;
```

```css
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export const CButton = styled(Button)`
  height: 80px;

  ${({ color }) =>
    color === "primary"
      ? css`
          background-color: green;
        `
      : color === "secondary" &&
        css`
          background-color: yellow;
        `}
`;
```

```js
import React from "react";

import CustomButton from "./CustomButton";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{
          marginBottom: "10px"
        }}
      >
        <CustomButton color="primary">Primary</CustomButton>
      </div>
      <div>
        <CustomButton color="secondary">Secondary</CustomButton>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image]

Could you tell me how I can get my styling to override the ui-material?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's unhelpful having snippets that don't run.  Can you create a codesandbox that runs?

Comment: Hey Chris, I'm sorry, I updated my code with codesandbox

Comment: @Tainara here is a working [https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-with-styled-components-e9fr5?file=/src/CustomButton.js](example) of the way you're trying to create a custom component. You need to increase the specificity to make the styles working with material ui components. As Chris mentioned, there is a nice example of the [https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#styled-components](Material) UI website.

Comment: Hey Junaid, that's work for me, thank you

Comment: Material UI [docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/) have some examples on how to customize the components using different approaches.

Comment: @Tainara JFYI, if you're planning to use a different color for primary and secondary in multiple components, you should try to create/modify the theme provided by Material ui [theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/). It'll save some time in creating different variations of the component, if you're planning to make such changes in multiple material ui components in your project, otherwise use the same approach, if you've very few changes.

Comment: got it, I'll see that Junaid, thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there's a nice example on how to do this in the material-ui docs:   https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#styled-components

One thing you seem to be missing is the `StylesProvider`, which allows your styles to override the default material styles.  This seems to work... I don't deal with the conditional in your example, but I don't think that's part of your problem here.

```
const MyStyledButton = styled(Button)`
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <div className="App">
        <MyStyledButton color="primary">Foo</MyStyledButton>
      </div>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

Here's a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-khorana-gnejy

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you, but how should I handle variations? How primary and secondary?

Comment: import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material' for latest version of material ui