# Why does a styled component add a margin when I have the margin attribute

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have 3 styled components on top of each other in a flex container, and the 2nd and third don't have the correct margin. They have an extra style with margin that overrides the one from StyledDiv but I'm not sure why.

I have a styled component like so

```
const StyledComponent = (props): JSX.Element => {
// assume all divs are flex
  return (
    <StyledDiv isExistingWorkflow={prop.exists}>
      <SomeComponent />
    </StyledDiv>
  )
}
const BorderDiv = styled.div<{ isExistingWorkflow: boolean }>`
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  border: ${(props) => (props.isExistingWorkflow ? '1px solid #d5dadf' : '1px dashed #0086C0')};
```

And then another which holds these:

```
const Component = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledComponent exists={true}/>
      <StyledComponent exists={true}/>
      <StyledComponent exists={false}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If I take the margin attribute and put it into the div like this `<div style={{margin: '1rem'}}>` I don't have the problem.
In the DOM, these first StyledComponent has this:
[image]

And then the following two StyledComponent have an extra style:
[image]

Why does the styled component add the extra style with the margin?

Comment: Relatively certain that this problem is due to a MUI style taking precedence over the style from the styled component for some reason:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68248337/how-to-override-material-ui-css-with-styled-component

Answer (score 1):

The reason is [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). When you put the style directly in the style object, that has the highest specificity and so overrides any other competing CSS. When you put it in `styled-components` it effectively puts the style against a CSS class and links the element to it. You have some other styles in some other component (probably the parent) that become relevant as they have a higher specificity. You need to find those styles you don't want and remove them.

You could also stick `!important` on like `margin: 1rem !important;` to force it to be higher specificity but this is generally seen as quite hacky.

Comment: So those two pictures, both come from the same component. The first picture belongs to the one at the top of the div, and the second picture belongs to the other two components in the div. I don't think I'm applying any different styles to the last two components.

Comment: I think Styled is adding the extra style `.iKwUXE`, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: The rule you have in place are based on the presence or not of the `style` prop, but also combines sibling selectors. The `:not(style)` stuff is quite odd and probably needs go.

Comment: Yea, I think the condition is causing the margin to be different for the same components, but I'm not sure why. The only thing the condition should affect is the border, not the margin

Comment: Actually it doesn't even matter if I have the condition or not. Even if all 3 components are the same, Having the components on top of each other adds the `:not(style) to the 2nd and third

Comment: So are you saying that in all of your styled components, `:not(style)` doesnt appear in your source code? Its possible that this :not(style) thing is some construct styled-components injects that im not even aware of, but just need to verify.

Comment: Basically this code could be on another component even, as it selects via a child selector. Use your IDE to search your entire codebase for the string `:not(style)` and see if you get any results.